# Python regex. Get the last word from a sequence

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a line like this:
`jsdata="l7Bhpb;_;CJWKh4 cECq7c;_;CJWKiA" data-ved="2ahUKEwjxq7L29Yr7AhWM7qQKHRABDVEQ2esEegQIGxAE">`

I need to get the word `CJWKiA`.
But I don't understand how to write it in the regex language.

My failed attempt:
`jsdata=\".+?;.+?\"`
This returns the entire string, including the word I need :(

I don't understand how to get only `CJWKiA` word, I need something pattern like this:
`jsdata=\"l7Bhpb;_;CJWKh4 cECq7c;_;(CJWKiA)\"`

There may be different words, I only need to get the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/jsdata="[^"]*;([^;"]*)"/gm
```

You can't have double quotes in the attribute.